# Is the same to add the files in repository using GitLab website as using cmd?

Tags: git, github

I have a java application and now I will push it to my repository in gitlab. What I did is I use gitlab website to do so . I created new directories and then I uploaded files to them. But I am not sure if this is the right way and if I have already done a commit or not since i have always used command prompt to do that. Anyway after that I decided to use command prompt so I clone my repository in Desktop and when I cloned it all the files I uploaded using gitlab website were inside this folder. Does it mean everything is pushed and commited ok? When I later type  **git . add --all**  and then  **git commit -m "Update it all "** it responds to me like " Nothing to commit , working directory clean". And after I use **git push** what I take as respond is: " Everything up-to-date" . I am worried if what i have done is really a push and is everything ok or i am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced with gitlab, but i would bet the UI is pretty much the same as using the cmd (at least for simple cases like yours).

If all the files are present after you clone the repo, don't worry, everything is updated.

I recommend you to use command line (or even some desktop GUI) instead of the website in the future: it provides you more control, and it is very easy to get at least the basics of git on cmd

Answer (score 0):

If you upload files in website it will create a commit default. 
And everything in the folder which you clone it means you push it successful.
So I think you do it the right way. 
Last thing, the push command maybe should "git add -A ."